# How to create a setup file that run on hosted server python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm creating a python app to get details from a website. I'm using selenium and pyodbc to create my app. It is getting all the details and saves them into a SQL server database. It is working fine on my pycharm IDE. Now I need to use this app on a hosted server like Linux or ubuntu server. How can I create a .exe file to run my app on a hosted server? And I used pyinstaller to create a .exe file using the following command.

```
pyinstaller --one main.py
```

I don't know what are the initial things that I should install on my server. Or is it not necessary to install any of the things to run my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this can help:

You can install python on your server and create a service in linux to run it. You don't have to create a .exe file. Also, .exe won't run on linux or ubuntu server.

Here's an article that can help you installing python on linux server:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-on-linux/

Here's an article on how to create a service in linux:
https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try these steps

Comment: And another matter, How Can I run it on a windows server? I'm new to python.

Comment: You can download python for windows also, but there's no direct way to run python scripts as windows service. So, you can use a tool called NSSM. Here's an article that can help: https://medium.com/@m_ko/how-to-run-python-scripts-as-a-windows-service-979082706360